# Firefox stuck on .htaccess redirect?

Tags: firefox, browser, apache-http-server, redirection

For the testing purposes I have put a *.htaccess* file in my local webserver to force the following redirect:

http://localhost/a-s/ → https://www.test-website.com/

After tests I have purged everything out entirely:

- the *.htaccess* file has been deleted
- the local server (XAMPP 8.2.4 for Windows) has been restarted

**Five different browsers**:

- Chrome, Edge on Windows hosting this URL
- Chrome, Samsung on Android accessing it
- Safari on iPad accessing this URL

Correctly respond to this change and the http://localhost/a-s/ is again entirely accessible in them. Firefox is a solely exception and it is stucked on the above redirect. Even 10+ minutes after *.htaccess* file removal it still redirect to test-website.com.

This is a weird as it can be:

- No browser should ever, never cache server-side redirects! As said, this is entirely server issue
- No idea how to stop this / refresh the local cache, because http://localhost/a-s/  is not accessible in browser

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Usually, (temporarily) disabling the cache from firefox's developer tools fixes problems like this

Comment: It depends on the HTTP Status Code and the domain name. Some redirects are **PERMANENT**. There is a difference between a 301 and a 307. Your question is low quality. No details are provided on the actual redirect issued by the backend. You also selected an answer that is again very low quality.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am not pretty much experienced in this stuff. But assuming: (a) localhost, (b) all other browsers adapting; Firefox not and (c) the fact that redirect was introduced by the file in the local system that is long-time gone; I'd rather say that this is a very weird bug in Firefox.

Comment: The first thing I would do is use the CLI curl to make requests and see the responses. I would document the problem at the HTTP layer instead of guessing what browsers do. Only then would I look for a solution. Don't forget to test in an Incognito Window as 301 redirects are permanent. The key strategy/skill is not to hack around. Know and document the problem before trying anything. That skill will be invaluable on complex issues later on.